# How to omit a view exposed filter if the displayed rows return a single selection value?

Tags: 8, views

Is there an option for that in views UI? If not then how to do it programmatically? In the twig template or a hook?

Comment: Can you use javascript? Meaning, can you check on the view rows and if a single selection value is present then hide the exposed filter?